# AJAX status nunca devuelve 200

Tags: javascript, ajax

Estoy haciendo una página simple para mostrar todas las imágenes que usa chromecast como presentación. He encontrado un archivo JSON en github con los enlaces a las imágenes. El problema está en que algunas ya no están en el servidor (devuelven 404), entonces mi idea es que antes de cargarlas, solicitar solamente la cabecera (función fetchHead) para no cargar el cuerpo de la imagen, si esta devuelve un 404, no la incluyo, pero parece ser que cuando el if es correcto (devuelve true porque el status de la cabecera es 200), siempre devuelve false, por lo tanto nunca se carga la imagen.

Voy a dejar el código, pero me parece que el problema está en el alcance del return...

```
probe = (a) => {
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    if (fetchHead(a[i].url)) {
        console.log("done");
    } else {
        console.log("err");
    }
}
};

fetchHead = (a) => {
    let head = new XMLHttpRequest();
    head.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readystate === 2) {
            if (this.status === 200) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    };
    head.open('HEAD', a);
    head.send();
};
```

Ni que decir tiene que el parámetro a es el objeto [JSON de github](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dconnolly/chromecast-backgrounds/master/backgrounds.json)

Me explico fatal, pero creo que con el código puede quedar claro...

Aclaro, en el for hay un 10 para no sobrecargar el servidor a llamadas, tener en cuenta que cada carga completa de esta página son unos 120MB de imágenes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Respondiendo a la pregunta**

Nunca devuelve 200 porque la propiedad `readystate` está mal escrita, es `readyState` con S mayúscula.

```js
let head = new XMLHttpRequest();
 head.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState === 2) {
            if (this.status === 200) {
                console.log(true);
            } else {
               console.log(false);
            }
        }
    };
    head.open('HEAD', 'https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-A0tXm8gjfMU/U08VDMRGtuI/AAAAAAAAvrI/IQEscTGZyJY/s1920-w1920-h1080-c/IMG_0293%2Bhe.jpg',true);
    head.send();
```

---

Hay dos formas de hacer las peticiones: asíncrona y síncrona.

Hacer lo siguiente:

```
if (fetchHead(a[i].url)) {
     console.log("done");
 }
```

Implica que sean peticiones síncronas, sin embargo eso tardaría más tiempo ya que se deben hacer una a una y esperar su resultado. Además la petición HTTP se está haciendo de forma asíncrona, o sea que hay una mezcla de intenciones en el código.

**Forma asíncrona**

Para que funcione de forma óptima, haciendo peticiones asíncronas, se hicieron un par de cambios al código original.

1. No se espera el resultado de la función `fetchHead()`. En lugar solo se itera el arreglo de urls y se llama la función `fetchHead()` por cada una para que todas las url se procesen de forma simultánea.
2. Relacionado al punto anterior, como todas las peticiones son asíncronas se agregó una función `callback()` que será llamada cuando todas las url hayan sido procesadas, dentro de `callback()` se pueden filtrar las url que funcionan y usarlas según se desee.

```js
let data = [
    {
        "url": "https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-A0tXm8gjfMU/U08VDMRGtuI/AAAAAAAAvrI/IQEscTGZyJY/s1920-w1920-h1080-c/IMG_0293%2Bhe.jpg",
        "author": "Ziv Horesh"
    },
    {
        "url": "https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-3LiF-MBl6OE/UO5TXZ724aI/AAAAAAAAE50/JWLqdeEM9QY/s1920-w1920-h1080-c/Colorado%2BRiver%2BSunset.jpg",
        "author": "Romain Guy"
    },
    {
        "url": "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-wkrGBuk0DoA/Us9JnUoXnTI/AAAAAAAAkTA/yDQexzLKhKY/s1920-w1920-h1080-c/DSC_0660.JPG",
        "author": "Alistair Nicol"
    }
];

// arreglo para guardar las url procesadas
// sean correctas o incorrectas
let checkedUrls = [];

fetchHead = (a) => {
    let head = new XMLHttpRequest();
    head.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (head.readyState == 4) {
            if (head.status == 200) {
                checkedUrls.push({ url : a, status : true })
            } else {
                checkedUrls.push({ data : a, status : false })
            }
            // si todas las url se han procesado
            // llamar al callback
            if(checkedUrls.length == data.length) callback();
        }
    };
    head.open('HEAD', a.url,true);
    head.send(null);
};

// llamar fetchHead por cada url, de esta forma se mantiene
// asíncrono
data.forEach(fetchHead);


function callback(){

  console.log('las  url se procesaron\nLas siguientes url son válidas:');
  // filtrar arreglo checkedUrls donde status sea true
  console.log(checkedUrls.filter(url => url.status));

}
```

**Forma síncrona**

Para esto se modificó la función `fetchHead()` para que haga las peticiones de forma síncrona, el código es más sencillo pero menos eficiente.

```js
let data = [
    {
        "url": "https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-A0tXm8gjfMU/U08VDMRGtuI/AAAAAAAAvrI/IQEscTGZyJY/s1920-w1920-h1080-c/IMG_0293%2Bhe.jpg",
        "author": "Ziv Horesh"
    },
    {
        "url": "https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-3LiF-MBl6OE/UO5TXZ724aI/AAAAAAAAE50/JWLqdeEM9QY/s1920-w1920-h1080-c/Colorado%2BRiver%2BSunset.jpg",
        "author": "Romain Guy"
    },
    {
        "url": "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-wkrGBuk0DoA/Us9JnUoXnTI/AAAAAAAAkTA/yDQexzLKhKY/s1920-w1920-h1080-c/DSC_0660.JPG",
        "author": "Alistair Nicol"
    }
];


probe = (a) => {
for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if (fetchHead(a[i].url)) {
        console.log("done");
    } else {
        console.log("err");
    }
}
};

fetchHead = (a) => {
    let head = new XMLHttpRequest();
    head.open('HEAD', a, false);
    head.send();
    return head.status == 200;
};

probe(data);
```